# Why would I use the CachePolicy returnCacheDataAndFetch for AWS AppSync queries?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have started using the AWS Amplify toolkit on an iOS, SwiftUI prototype.  The guide has this for runQuery:

```
func runQuery(){
    appSyncClient?.fetch(query: ListTodosQuery(), cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataAndFetch) {(result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            return
        }
        result?.data?.listTodos?.items!.forEach { print(($0?.name)! + " " + ($0?.description)!) }
    }
}
```

When I call it, I get duplicate items in output - cached and fetched.

What is the purpose of the returnCacheDataAndFetch policy? How is this policy used in practice?

NOTE: I have a few changes, not using the Todos but just a generic MyType from the aws cli generator.

```swift
func runMutation(){
    let mutationInput = CreateMyTypeInput(title: "Use AppSync", content:"Realtime and Offline")
    appSyncClient?.perform(mutation: CreateMyTypeMutation(input: mutationInput)) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error as? AWSAppSyncClientError {
            print("Error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription )")
        }
        if let resultError = result?.errors {
            print("Error saving the item on server: \(resultError)")
            return
        }
    }
}

func runQuery(){
    appSyncClient?.fetch(query: ListMyTypesQuery(), cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataAndFetch) {(result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            return
        }
        result?.data?.listMyTypes?.items!.forEach { print(($0?.id)! + " " + ($0?.title)! + " " + ($0?.content)!) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`returnCacheDataAndFetch` is used in case if you need to improve the UI response time and experience of the app by providing data from the cache where network delay is not acceptable however stale data is acceptable.